# Non-functioning view when sharing controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple app that fetches images from Flickr and renders them. The application is divided into two views, `SearchView` and `PhotoListView`. Previously, when treating these as one view, everything worked fine, and photos were rendered. Now, when sharing controller, both are rendered but the list of photos is never populated. When debugging I can see that the photos are indeed fetched.

I'm terribly new at Angular, so I really don't have any good guesses at what the problem could be, but possibly that the two views don't share scope properly?

Here's the routing (using `ui-router`):

```
// app.js

'use strict';

angular.module('pruApp', ['ui.state'])
    .config(function ($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/photos');
        $stateProvider
            .state('/', {
                url: '/photos',
                views: {
                    'SearchView': {
                        templateUrl: '/views/search.html',
                        controller: 'PhotoCtrl'
                    },
                    'PhotoListView': {
                        templateUrl: '/views/photo-list.html',
                        controller: 'PhotoCtrl'
                    }
                }
            });

        // Remove X-Requested-With header to enable CORS
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    });
```

The controller and factory that talks to the Flickr service:

```
// photo.js

'use strict';

angular.module('pruApp')
    .controller('PhotoCtrl', function ($scope, PhotoFactory) {
        $scope.search = function() {
            PhotoFactory.getPhotos($scope.searchQuery).then(function (data) {
                $scope.photos = [];

                var parsedData = angular.fromJson(data);
                var items = parsedData.photos.photo;

                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
                    var photo = items[i];
                    $scope.photos.push({
                        title: photo.title,
                        image: 'http://farm' + photo.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret + '_m.jpg',
                        link: 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/' + photo.owner + '/' + photo.id
                    });
                }
            });
        };
    });

angular.module('pruApp')
    .factory('PhotoFactory', function ($http, $q) {
        return {
            _get: function(url) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $http.get(url)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status) {
                        deferred.reject('An error occured: ' + status);
                    });

                return deferred.promise;
            },
            getPhotos: function (searchQuery) {
                return this._get('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=<MY_KEY>&tags=' + searchQuery + '&format=json&nojsoncallback=1');
            }
        };
    });
```

This is where the views are injected:

```
<!-- index.html -->

<div class="main" role="main">
    <div class="search" ui-view="SearchView"></div>
    <div class="results" ui-view="PhotoListView"></div>
</div>
```

Search template:

```
<!-- search.html -->

<h2 class="struct">Search</h2>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="cell">
            <input type="search" name="search-query" class="search-query" placeholder="Search photos by tags (e.g. lolcat, rageface, bronie)" ng-model="searchQuery" required>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <button type="submit" name="search-button" class="search-button" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Photo list template:

```
<!-- photo-list.html -->

<h2 class="struct">Search results</h2>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="photo in photos">
        <h3>{{ photo.title }}</h3>
        <a href="{{ photo.link }}"><img ng-src="{{ photo.image }}" alt="{{ photo.title }}"></a>
        <p class="author">Author: <span>{{ photo.author }}</span></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem seems to be that you are calling the method to get the photos on one instance of the controller but that doesn't share data with your other controller.  On first read I had missed your factory definition, still the problem is the variable in scope on the controller is in a different instance.

The way you can handle this is by always returning a promise from the factory/service to the controller, the in the controller using the promise to assign the scope.  This way if the service has data already available it will automatically populate in your controllers scope, and if not as soon as it comes available it can be populated.

Really it looks like you're doing what I'm saying in the paragraph above but I don't see where the search function is called within the controller.  Essentially you should just have something in the controller that is populating the $scope.photos array directly off the service.  Then separately you should have your search function which fires off the call to the service passing along the parameter.

Another option is to $watch your properties in the factory/service and update a variable in the $scope of the controller on changes.

```
angular.module('pruApp')
    .factory('PhotoFactory', function ($http, $q) {
        return {
            photos: [],
            _get: function(url) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $http.get(url)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        this.photos = [];

                        var parsedData = angular.fromJson(data);
                        var items = parsedData.photos.photo;

                        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
                            var photo = items[i];
                            this.photos.push({
                                title: photo.title,
                                image: 'http://farm' + photo.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret + '_m.jpg',
                                link: 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/' + photo.owner + '/' + photo.id
                            });
                        }
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status) {
                        deferred.reject('An error occured: ' + status);
                    });

                return deferred.promise;
            },
            getPhotos: function (searchQuery) {
                return this._get('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=<MY_KEY>&tags=' + searchQuery + '&format=json&nojsoncallback=1');
            }
        };
    });
```

and in the controller

```
angular.module('pruApp')
    .controller('PhotoCtrl', function ($scope, PhotoFactory) {
            $scope.$watch(function () { return PhotoFactory.photos; }, function(data) {
                 $scope.photos = data;
            }); // initialize the watch

            $scope.search = function() {
                PhotoFactory.getPhotos($scope.searchQuery);
            };
        }
    });
```

Comment: To clarify, `search()` is called when clicking the button in the search view. `$scope.search` is declared as first and only function in the controller.

Comment: @Jorum, right what I'm saying is it's not called within the controller and there are multiple instances of the controller, I'll see if I can modify your code to show how I think it should be handled.  If search() is called on the controller used for view1 it won't have been called for the controller on view2 so that view won't have it's scope's photos array populated.

Comment: An example would be awesome. Also, thanks for your efforts. Like I said I'm new to Angular, still trying to get the hang of the concepts.

Comment: @Jorum See the edits I made above there may be syntax errors as I was just editing on SO let me know if you run into errors you can't debug.  Basically I moved some of your data processing code into the service and am storing the data in the service, then in the controller I'm just watching the service's property for changes.

Comment: There's another couple of ways to do this but I posted the one I've actually used in practice.

Comment: That did the trick! Though I did have to cache `this` in the beginning of `_get()`.